# Moving answers that are really comments to comments section

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn answer into comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/turn-answer-into-comment)

Or "how to stop new users from posting comments as answers."

One way to cut down on the number of comments/questions being posted by new users as answers would be to create a quick and easy means for a user with moderate yet sufficient reputation to move said answer to the question's comments (or even another answer's comments). This quick and easy way could be a button in the answer titled `move to comments` or something.

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632909/using-librarystacks-in-a-scatterview-on-surface/1861870#1861870), a new user wanted to know if the question asker had found a solution to their problem, but since they lacked the reputation necessary to made a comment on the question itself, they asked it in an answer instead. This should have obviously been made as a comment on the question, but the person asking the question lacked the reputation necessary to do so.

Comment: Motivation behind it or not, the heart of this suggestion is much the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/turn-answer-into-comment. You also have http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments for the moderator-restricted version.

Comment: @Grace Somehow I missed those. It'd be nice if a reason was given for `status-declined`, though.

Comment: There's a point to be made too, that people without reputation enough to post comments can post answers - and do in lieu of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If a user posts a comment as an answer, flag it for moderator attention, or downvote it. Or both.

Comment: For the guy who advocates [punishing those who participate in duplicate posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows), it's kinda surprising that you'd post an answer. Not bad or anything. Just surprising.

Comment: @Grace In my perfect world this would be whisked away and 301 redirected. Until that happens I don't want newcomers to Meta to feel like everyone hates them because a good number of questions are closed as duplicates (because they've been answered *ad nauseum*). With any luck in two days this question will be deleted, and the OP will see the duplicate link at the top.

Comment: @Grace Now that I see the answers in that question; I'm glad I answered. I went ahead and added that answer to that question. There was a shortage of succinct answers over there.

Comment: Ooh, good call there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start flagging what I see.