# Alert the moderators when you see a reply which would've better been a comment to the original question?

Tags: discussion, moderator-abilities

When I see [a reply like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450510/dynamic-data-different-views-for-the-same-table) I was wondering if it's best to contact a moderator about it to merge it as a comment on the original question? I don't have access to moderation tools myself due to lack of enough points so it could well be that this becomes available for me when I earn that level?

Edit: to clarify a bit why the question is because I'm a moderator myself over at http://forums.asp.net, ( http://forums.asp.net/members/xiii.aspx) but I would like to know how to behave on these forums as well.

Comment: I think you "misunderestimate" the 10k tools -- all they give is greater visibility as to types of questions (voted to be closed, deleted, and offensive/spam flags), and to cast delete and undelete votes.  Only diamond moderators can manipulate other people's posts like that.

Comment: That would seem to contradict the FAQ ("At the high end of this reputation spectrum there is little difference between users with high reputation and ♦  moderators. That is very much intentional. We don't run Stack Overflow. The community does.") and is a bit of a surprise to me...

Comment: You may wanna look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/turn-answer-into-comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the following:

- Downvoted the poster. This will also encourage the poster to delete his post in order to get the lost reputation back. (Requires 100 reputation.)
- Left a comment explaining why I downvoted so that they understand the reason for the downvote. (Requires 50 reputation.)
- Edited the question to include the comment from the OP. (Requires 2000 reputation.)

The first two steps do not require all that much reputation so most users would be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave a comment for the poster (who can then delete his answer and repost as a comment), or you can flag for moderator attention (you don't need mega-rep for this), and ask a mod to help out. I typically do the latter when it's an old post.

Comment: I'd prefer both. Saves me from having to do the comment part myself. (But if the poster hasn't visited for three months or something, don't bother with the comment.)