# Way to convert an answer to a comment?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, answers, comment-replies

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672964/function-works-properly-with-relative-path-input-but-not-with-absolute-path-input) which Dennis Washington correctly pointed should have been a comment than an answer.

Is there any way to change an answer to a comment while still respecting the sentiments of the contributor to help intact?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This feature was recently introduced for diamond moderators. Flag your post for moderator attention and make a note that you would like it turned into a comment, and it will be taken care of shortly.

Comment: I have flagged that question for moderator attention..Thank you. However, not sure what would happen to the comments to my answers though..

Comment: @TheCottonSilk IIRC, comments can be preserved if the moderator deems it appropriate.

Comment: Oh I see..that's very flexible! Nice to know that.

Answer (score 2):

I would just copy the answer, comment it, and delete the answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, one can always do that when there are no comments to my answer.. However, it would not be a good idea to delete my answer to convert it to a comment in turn deleting the other users comments to my answer. Instead if there is a way to do it in the system itself, then it can take all the comments to my answer as well in the comments section..

Comment: ooh that would be a nice feature