# What should we do when a message should be a comment?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to convert an answer to a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74815/way-to-convert-an-answer-to-a-comment)

Please check it: [Facebook API login page in iPhone displays huge webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540369/facebook-api-login-page-in-iphone-displays-huge-webpage) in this question last answer is suppose to be comment. What are we suggested to do with these type of answers?

Answer (score 3):

I just clicked the "flag" link on the answer and chose "not an answer". As a result, a moderator will review it and take appropriate action.

Note that this flag is only for things posted as an answer which are not semantically an answer; things like obvious comments, and posts that basically are only a link, with no attempt to "answer" the question. Also, often you'll see follow up questions posted as an answer.

But don't use the "not an answer"  flag for things which are just "bad" answers... No matter how bad, incorrect, misunderstanding, irrelevant the answer may be.