# How to review comment-as-an-answer in Low Quality queue?

Tags: discussion, comments, review, low-quality-posts

How to review comment-as-an-answer in Low Quality queue **when, and only when** the answerer states ["I can't comment on the answer given"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6216876) or similar? (*Update:* this answer, which very well may have been helpful to the OP, has been deleted.)

Since the answerer is already aware it should be a comment, the deletion comment template --

> “This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.”

-- doesn't help, and makes reviewers sound ignorant.

Could we either lower the [comment privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) from 50 rep to, say, 10 rep? If this is to be the case, I propose comments by users with less than 50 rep be put in the [first posts queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts).

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii But should deletion be recommended, or not?

Comment: Yes, delete it (as animuson said).

Comment: Related feature request: [Add 'Change (answer) to comment' option to review page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146273/add-change-answer-to-comment-option-to-review-page)

Answer (score 9):

Whether or not they've identified that they can't comment is not relevant. A comment is not an answer and should be deleted. If you don't feel the comments in the list are relevant or useful to the person who posted, then choose the "no comment" option at the top. I do so all the time.

As for lowering the reputation threshold, that has [already been discussed and is currently declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment).

Comment: Also worth noting that folks who can't comment are often *terrible* judges of what should/shouldn't be comments - hence the reason for the restriction in the first place! I've seen folks post quite reasonable answers while complaining that they couldn't comment, and of course untold numbers of worthless "I can't comment but I want to ask if you ever found a solution" answers.