# Do mods have the ability to convert answers from users with less than 15 rep to comments?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I am aware of the ability of mods to [convert answers to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/turn-answer-into-comment). However, I'm wondering if this extends to invoking it on answers from all users, regardless of the answering user's commenting privileges. I don't thoroughly check a lot of comments for rep levels, and if this does occur, I haven't seen it myself.

If this is the case, I have this strange suspicion that it has created an opening in the privilege continuum or something. It's a great way of tidying things up, and I *do* see the point of requiring rep in order to comment, but I just now saw and flagged a [(non-)answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515032/android-camera-intent-creating-two-files/5051246#5051246) from a 1-rep user that began with:

> (Sorry, not an answer.)

I note that I think this particular answer would be more appropriately converted to a question as opposed to a comment, but still... it made me think a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mods can convert any answer to a comment (on the question or on another answer), regardless of the reputation of the author. On SE sites I think it's the common case, as people are new to the engine and might not even realize commenting exists (the "add comment" link isn't displayed at all for low rep users)