# Inappropriate review audit answer for "FTPS versus SFTP versus SCP"

Tags: bug, disputed-review-audits

A while ago I failed a review audit because of the known problem that [adding a comment to a highly upvoted post is being considered bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197439/220244) and that the answer is not completely correct.

- The failed review audit: https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/174959
- The inappropriate answer with my comment: https://superuser.com/a/677971/61370

Could you please remove the answer from the audit pool if it does not get corrected?

Also please do something with the problem that [adding a comment to a highly upvoted post is being considered bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197439/220244). Such unjustly failed audits discourage reviewers from voluntary help to Stack Exchange.

Comment: I have solved (I hope) the acute problem by down-voting the answer. It seems that a single down-vote will prevent the post from appearing in review audits: [Review audit seems wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196883/220244)